# PHP8 - Fatal User Error: Unsupported operand types: array & int

Tags: php, php-8

I am trying to fix some PHP8 errors in forum software, need assistance with this.

Error thrown is Fatal User Error: Unsupported operand types: array & int on these lines.

```
$forumperms & $this->registry->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['cangetattachment'],
$forumperms & $this->registry->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['canseethumbnails']
```

For reference the whole code section below.

```
/*
* Processes any attachments to this post.
*/
function process_attachments()
{
    global $show;

    $forumperms = fetch_permissions($this->thread['forumid']);
    require_once(DIR . '/packages/vbattach/attach.php');
    $attach = new vB_Attach_Display_Content($this->registry, 'vBForum_Post');

    if ($this->post['allattachments'])
    {
        foreach($this->post['allattachments'] AS $attachmentid => $info)
        {
            if (!$this->post['attachments'][$attachmentid])
            {
                unset($this->post['allattachments'][$attachmentid]);
            }
        }

        $attach->process_attachments(
            $this->post,
            $this->post['allattachments'],
            (THIS_SCRIPT == 'external'),
            can_moderate($this->forum['forumid'], 'canmoderateattachments'),
            $forumperms & $this->registry->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['cangetattachment'], //ERROR
            $forumperms & $this->registry->bf_ugp_forumpermissions['canseethumbnails']  //ERROR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $show['attachments'] =  $show['moderatedattachment'] = $show['thumbnailattachment'] = $show['otherattachment'] = false;
        $show['imageattachment'] = $show['imageattachmentlink'] = false;
    }
}
```

Have not tried anything yet trying to work out how those lines must be changed for PHP8 compatability.

Comment: What you think should be the result of logical AND between array and int?

Answer (score -1):

Unsupported operand type errors occurred when some kind of mathematical calculation was involved in some part of the code and one of the operands could not be automatically converted to the other type. In your case, **the calculation seems to have one operand as int and the other one being an array** and an array could not be automatically converted to int, hence the issue.

In your code, the 2 lines that you have marked as the error-causing lines are not the actual point of error. Starting from PHP **8** strict typings have been introduced almost everywhere in PHP core functions so legacy code will break. You can read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php)

I think you need to check for `vB_Attach_Display_Content::process_attachments` method for any mathematical calculations. In the given code block you are passing different parameters to that function and maybe those parameters are not strictly typed. Hence the function is accepting anything.

Comment: You cannot do a bitwise and `&` on an array :)